# ComponentOne Combobox Interactions MVVM

Tags: mvvm, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0, componentone

I am working with ComponentOne WPF Controls with MVVM Pattern.

I have the following in my ViewModel:

```
 public ICommand ClientsEnter
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.m_ClientsEnter == null)
                {
                    this.m_ClientsEnter = new DelegateCommand<string>(ClientsLostFocusExecute, ClientsLostFocusCanExecute);
                }
                return m_ClientsEnter;
            }
        }
```

And an observable collection :

```
 public ObservableCollection<Client> Clients
        {
            get { return m_Clients; }
            set
            {
                m_Clients = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Clients");
            }
        }
```

in Xaml I have Added A ComponentOne Combo Box where I can enter `ClientName` Or `ID` and press enter to fire Event to execute `ClientsEnter` Command:

```
<Custom1:C1ComboBox  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Height="24" Name="cmbClients" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Clients, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedValuePath="ClientID" DisplayMemberPath="NameE" IsEditable="True"
                Text="Enter Client Name Or ID" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Filter.ClientID, Mode=TwoWay}" MinWidth="150" Margin="0,2" Width="189">
              <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <ei:KeyTrigger Key="Tab"  FiredOn="KeyUp" ActiveOnFocus="True" SourceName="cmbClients">
                  <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClientsEnter, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text,ElementName=cmbClients}" CommandName="KeyDown"/>
                </ei:KeyTrigger>
              </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Custom1:C1ComboBox>
```

I need to know why it doesn't work, after pressing enter the `clientID` Disappears and nothing happens.  Even the `text="Enter Client Name Or ID"` doesn't appear!  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After spending 2 days investigating this issue ,i discover that there is a bug in C1Combobox as i replaced it with telerik Comboxbox and add the same trigger without changing anything in xaml except the control and it works fine.

finally,i dont recommend C1 wpf controls